# EF entity result returns null for column that is not null in db

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Getting a strange result when pulling data from my database. In one case, I have a datetime field that is not null in the database and has a valid date. But when EF returns the records, it is returning null.

If I use the same sql statement that EF is using and run it in SSMS, it is returning the correct value.

I think it is because it already cached that record and is returning the cached version...is that possible? How can you force it to refresh from the database?

Here is my code that pulls the records:

```
 public override IQueryable<TimeDetail> SearchFor(Expression<Func<TimeDetail, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<TimeDetail, bool>> orderbylinq = null, Expression<Func<TimeDetail, object>>[] includes = null)
        {
            var result = DbSet
                .Include("Customer")
                .Include("OrderHeader")
                .Include("TimeDetailStatus")
                .Include("TimeDetailTask.TimeDetailTaskType")
                .Where(predicate);

            if (orderbylinq != null)
            {
                result = result.OrderBy(orderbylinq);
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Comment: Try to call `ToList()` method to get the concret result instead using Iqueryable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `DbSet` is your `DbContext`. In order to *refresh* it, you need to recreate it.

Something like:

```
DbSet = new DbSet();
```

Comment: you are 2 for 2 this morning matty! Thanks.

Comment: @ChadRichardson LOL I didn't realise you were the same asker! No problems :) glad I could help, again!

Comment: Hey where to do that ?